# $y=\frac{a}{n^2-p^2}(\sin\,pt -\frac{p}{n}\,\sin\,nt)$ Show that, as $p$ tends to $n$, $y$ tends to $\frac{a}{2n}(\frac{1}{n}\,\sin\,nt-t\,\cos\,nt)$

Tags: limits

$$y=\frac{a}{n^2-p^2}(\sin\,pt -\frac{p}{n}\,\sin\,nt)$$

Show that, as $p$ tends to $n$, $y$ tends to

$$\frac{a}{2n}(\frac{1}{n}\,\sin\,nt-t\,\cos\,nt)$$

When the question states that $p$ tends to $n$, doesn't it mean the value of $p$ is approaching the value of $n$?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual meaning of "p tends to n"

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{p\to n}a\frac{\sin pt-\frac pn\sin nt}{n^2-p^2}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=a\lim_{p\to n}\frac{t\cos pt-\frac1n\sin nt}{-2p}=a\frac{\frac1n\sin nt-t\cos nt}{2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Use L'hopitale rule. Can you continue?